# Hibernate reveng persistence model does not validate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, validation

I use Hibernate Reverse Engineering to automatically create classes from a database scheme. DB server is MSSQL 2008. This database is designed by a partner and could potentially change without notice. Thus I'd like to have Hibernate validate the scheme on startup, wich in my opinion should work out of the box. But it doesn't:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in somedb.dbo.ASVC_S for column SomeCol. Found: decimal, expected: numeric(18,0)
```

The generated enttity class looks like this:

```
@Column(name="SomeCol", precision=18)
public BigDecimal getSomeCol() {
    return this.someCol;
}
```

Is my assumption that reveng creates classes that can be validated against the schema wrong? Should I skip validation and hope that during runtime everything's OK? Annotating the classes after generating them or maintaining an entry for each class in my reveng.xml mapping file is not an option - too many classes ;)

hibernate-tools is version 4.0.0-CR1.